# Recursion function subtracting accumulated percentage with <<-

Tags: recursion, memory-management, r

I have a file with percentage of presence of micro-organisms but each category has the accumulation of percentages of the child categories. I designed a recursive function to subtract the proportion on those categories. In order to reduce the problem that on the real dataset I end up with many samples having 800% of micro-orangisms.

```
#' Delete repeated information
#'
#' Each parent class has the sum of the proportion of the descendent class.
#' This function delete those rows that don't bring information.
#' @param taxonomy The names of the otus
#' @param otus The accumulative percentage of abundance of each taxon
#' @return The percentage of abundance of each otu taxon
cleanRel <- function(taxonomy, otus) {

    check <- function(tax) {
        message("Looking at ", colnames(taxonomy)[1], " for ", tax)

        if (ncol(taxonomy) >= 2) {

            tax_f <- taxonomy[, 1] %in% tax

            # Find the porportion of each subcategory
            lvl <- levels(droplevels(taxonomy[tax_f, 2]))
            subTax <- sapply(lvl, function(x) {
                # From those taxa in the current level
                # # Find each of the sublevels
                tax_x <- taxonomy[tax_f, 2] %in% x
                o <- otus[tax_f, ]
                y <- o[tax_x, ]

                if (is.null(dim(y))) {
                    y
                } else if (ncol(y) > 0) {
                    apply(y, 2, max)
                } else {
                    stop("Unexpected category")
                }
            })

            # Depending on the dimensions of subTax transform it
            if (!is.null(dim(subTax))){
                if (nrow(subTax) == ncol(otus)) {
                    subTax <- rowSums(subTax)
                } else {
                    stop("check the dimension of subTax")
                }
            } else {
                if (length(subTax) == ncol(otus)) {
                    subTax <- subTax
                } else {
                    subTax <- rep(0, ncol(otus))
                }
            }

            # Find the row to subtract from
            keepRow <- tax_f & is.na(taxonomy[, 2])

            if (sum(keepRow) > 1) {
                stop("Several rows matched for the same taxon")
            }

            # Subtract the values of each sub taxa
            otus[keepRow, ] <<- otus[keepRow, ] - subTax


            # Iterate to the following list if it suits
            if (ncol(taxonomy) > 2){
                otus[tax_f, ] <<- cleanRel(droplevels(taxonomy[tax_f, -1]), otus[tax_f, ])
                return(otus)
            } else {
                return(otus)
            }

        } else {
            return(otus)
        }

    }

    sapply(levels(droplevels(taxonomy[, 1])), check)
    otus
}
```

My concern is with using `<<-`, it was the only way I could think about modifying always the same matrix. Also it is maybe the third recursive function I write, so I might have filled it with `return`, to make it work.
At some point I had problems with the memory usage, so I modified the the line where it calls itself from `otus <<- cleanRel(taxonomy[, -1], otus)` to `otus[tax_f, ] <<- cleanRel(droplevels(taxonomy[tax_f, -1]), otus[tax_f, ])` (That's why I tag it with memory-managment), but I think the problem is related to the assignation `<<-`

My test case is:

```
library("testthat")
test_that("handmade", {
    o <- structure(c(1.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1.5, 0, 0, 1.5, 0, 3, 1.5, 1.5, 0,
                     1.5, 1.5, 2.4, 1.2, 0.3, 0.2, 1.2, 0.3), .Dim = c(6L, 4L))
    m <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                                       .Names = c("1", "2", "3", "", "4", "5"),
                                       .Label = "A", class = "factor"),
                        V2 = structure(c(NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L),
                                       .Names = c("1", "2", "3", "", "4", "5"),
                                       .Label = c("Ab", "Bb"), class = "factor"),
                        V3 = structure(c(NA, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L),
                                       .Names = c("1", "2", "3", "", "4", "5"),
                                       .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor")),
                   .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), row.names = c(NA, 6L),
                   class = "data.frame")
    b <- cleanRel(m, o)
    expect_equal(dim(b), dim(o))
    of <- structure(c(1.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.5, 0, 0, 1.5, 0, 0, 0, 1.5,
                      0, 0, 1.5, 0, 0.7, 0.3, 0.2, 0.9, 0.3), .Dim = c(6L, 4L))
    expect_equal(b, of)
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not to discourage you from using recursion, I think there is a much simple approach to your problem. If you build two vectors of ids and parent ids:

```
id  <- gsub(" NA", "", do.call(paste, m))
pid <- sub(" ?\\S+$", "", id)
```

Then you can just loop on each id to identify its children and subtract their contribution to the cumulative sum:

```
b <- matrix(NA, nrow(o), ncol(o))
for (i in 1:nrow(o)) {
  children <- pid == id[i]
  b[i, ] <- o[i, ] - colSums(o[children, , drop = FALSE])
}

expect_equal(b, of)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the iterative approach,  a team-mate advised me against using the recursive function. It is easier to understand and to maintain (and you came up with a better solution in much much less time!!).